# R reading multiple raster files gives error in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 500 tif files (`ind_moist1.tif`, `ind_moist2.tif`,`ind_moist3.tif`......`ind_moist500.tif`) in my working directory. I want to read each one of them. Here is what I did:

```
library(raster)
for (i in 1:500){
moist[i]<-raster(paste0("R:/....moist_tif/ind_moist",i,".tif"))
}
```

I get the error saying `object moist not found`. Could anyone tell me what is it I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `raster(paste("R:........moist_tif/moist",i,".tif", sep=""))`

Comment: thank you. But it still says object moist not found. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Before the loop try: `moist <- rep(NA, 500)`

Comment: Now I get this error when I add `moist<-rep(NA, 500)`. `incompatible types (from S4 to logical) in subassignment type fix`

Comment: Oh boy ;) Well another way is to try a list: `moist <- list()`

Comment: Thanks. This one works. However, I do not want to work with list. I just want to access the object by their name i.e. after reading, I should be able to type moist1, moist2, moist3 to access them for which your first solution was fine but I need to check why it is not working in my case. Thank you again

Comment: Would be nice if you could report whether the updated answered solved the problem and accept it if it does so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `moist` to be a list before the loop:

```
moist <- list()
```

And inside the loop add items via

```
moist[paste0("moist",i)] <- raster...
```

Then you can access them via `moist$moist1`, `moist$moist2`, ...or use `attach(moist)` to get acces directly via `moist1`, `moist2`,...

**UPDATE:** Picking up Konrad's comment you can do

```
i <- 1:500
listMoist <- lapply(i, FUN = function(x) { raster(paste0("R:/....moist_tif/ind_moist",x,".tif")) })
names(listMoist) <- paste0("moist",i)
```

Use `attach(listMoist)` to again get acces to the individual list entries via their names. Not sure how much faster this is. Give it a try and report back ;)

Comment: Don’t grow lists in a loop, it’s inefficient — and completely unnecessary: just do an `lapply`.